# Tableau SAML authentication with Auth0 authenticates user but does not logs out of system

Tags: single-sign-on, tableau-api, saml, auth0

I have developed a react application in which I am embedding graphs using tableau-api. I have configured the SAML authentication for tableau with Auth0 as a SSO. When I login with Auth0 using same email id which has access of tableau, tableau allows me to access graph. Everything works fine up to this point. Now the problem is when I logout of the auth0, the Auth0 sessions are terminated but the tableau session still remains active. So I can still access the tableau graph even after logging out of Auth0. How can I also logout of the tableau online?

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: Quote "Now the problem is when I logout of the auth0, the Auth0 sessions are terminated but the tableau session still remains active. So I can still access the tableau graph even after logging out of Auth0. How can I also logout of the tableau online?"

**Answer**:
In your SSO use case, tableau is SAML service provider (or relying party), Auth0 is SAML identity provider.

tableau leverages Auth0 to perform identity authentication (or login authentication). As SAML identity provider, Auth0 establishs the authentication session for tableau and then federates the user identity (or user info) to tableau.
As SAML service provider and a web app, tableau establishes the login session to keep session alive for an uncertain period (such as 1 hour or 8 hours). Once the session is alive, you can still access the tableau graph.

SAML identity provider Auth0 can NOT revoke the session established by tableau. Thus, Quote "when I logout of the auth0, the Auth0 sessions are terminated but the tableau session still remains active."

**Resolution**:
(1) You need to create a logout button for tableau to perform the two tasks below:

(I) Delete the session established by tableau.

(II) Post the single logout request to Auth0 SLO API to remove the authentication session for tableau. (Or If you do NOT want to develop SLO request feature, you just log out of Auth0 to remove all the sessions for all web applications including tableau.)

You can find the SAML Single Logout (SLO) Service API from the metadata of Auth0 SAML identity provider, such as

```
<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://tableau.auth0.com/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SLO"/>
```

A sample of metadata of SAML identity provider can be found in the GitHub link below.

[Shibboleth SAML IdP metadata](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP/blob/master/shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/metadata/idp-metadata.xml)

(2) The following [Shibboleth Logout Discussion](https://docs.shib.ncsu.edu/docs/logout.html) provides the typical solution on how to completely remove the session of a SAML SP app (such as tableau) from SAML IdP.

Logging out from Shibboleth is complicated, because there are at least three levels of sessions you must consider for removal:

- Your application session. For example: a Drupal site that checks shibboleth at login to create a session. Once the session is started, the login is not checked again. It is assumed that the user of that session is always the same.
- Your Service Provider (SP) session. The SP on your server creates a session in memory, and tracks this session with a browser cookie.
- The Identity Provider (IdP) session. When the user logs in to the IdP, they get a session cookie that lets the IdP remember that it has seen the user before. If the same user goes to login to another shibboleth SP, the IdP can reuse the login and pass the appropriate message to the new SP without another login.

In addition, the user may have used their IdP session to authenticate to other SPs in addition. Those SPs will have their own SP sessions and could have additional application sessions as well.

The best that you can do for a logout is:

- Remove your application session by whatever means is appropriate for the given application.
- Remove your SP session. Your SP handler must do this, as the cookie is tied to the session in memory. The SP must terminate the session as well as remove the session cookie.
- Remove the IdP session. You must send the user back to one of the Identity Provider logout URLs so it can terminate the IdP session and remove its session cookie.
- In order to force the user to logout of other SP sessions or applications, the IdP must be configured to support Single Logout (SLO). When enabled, the IdP will track every SP login for the user using browser local storage. When an SLO is requested, a javascript page runs to visit every stored SP session and perform the logout. This is not a perfect solution, and it adds a noticeable slowdown to the login process for the browser memory storage. We do not currently support SLO on shib.ncsu.edu.
- The best practice is to ask the user to close their browser which should cause it to discard the required cookies. That will not terminate the sessions, so anyone holding those cookies could still use them.

Comment: Ok I will try above solution

Comment: Hi @winstonhong, we are facing the same logout issue as you describe. In your resolution you mentioned '(I) Delete the session established by tableau'. Can you please elaborate on how this is accomplished? Is there an API endpoint to call? Are you deleting a specific cookie? How do we do this? Thanks!

Comment: @yossi-geretz Yes. Your "tableau" app (which is SAML service provider) need to post Logout request with specific session ID (assigned by Auth0) to the SAML Single Logout (SLO) Service API of Auth0 (which is SAML identity provider), then Auth0 will delete the session cookie for your "tableau" app. Please check Auth0 metadata to get SLO API such as (your-organization.auth0.com/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SLO). I have updated my answer by adding extra solution on how to remove SAML single logout session,

Comment: @winstonhong, thank you for additional information and suggestions. You are saying, that our Tableau app needs to post the Logout request
- how we can trigger that post Logout request from our website
(Tableau Online reports are embedded into our web-site (with Auth0 SAML SSO))? Information about our particular issue can be found on -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738139/issue-with-logout-from-tableau-online-saml-when-using-auth0-identity-provider

Comment: SP-Initiated Single Logout is straightforward, see http://www.componentspace.com/forums/24/spinitiated-single-logout However, according to your link to another StackOverflow question, If Tableau does NOT support SP-Initiated SLO, you still require Tableau to host the link for IdP-Initiated SLO.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is implement single logout service and configure it to support idp initiated logout.

Then when idp logout happens it will call back to your logout service and provide you information about the successful logout from idp.

Then you need to perform a local logout based on the information received from idp.

You need to include this whole thing in your single logout service and you need to register it in idp(Auth0).