# Issue with logout from Tableau Online SAML when using Auth0 Identity provider

Tags: single-sign-on, tableau-api, saml-2.0, auth0, auth0-lock

We are using Tableau Online to integrate reports into our website. We are using Auth0 as SAML SSO Identity provider for Tableau.

We have an issue with Logout from Tableau when logging out from our website (via Auth0).
When non-tableau user (not defined on tableau side) logs into our website after tableau user logged out, he can still see Tableau report on our website (instead of Tableau login prompt). This only happens in the same browser instance.

We integrated Auth0 with Tableau as described in the following article [configuring auth0 as sso idp for tableau](https://alexeskinasy.medium.com/configuring-auth0-as-sso-idp-for-tableau-115707ca1d0c)

We use IdP-initiated SLO (Auth0 logout call) and since Tableau doesn’t support it [regarding Tableau requirements](https://help.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/saml_online_requ.htm), we are not able to logout from Tableau.

To use SP-initiated SLO to comply with Tableau requirements, it looks like it is needed to logout from Tableau Online explicitly. But that is not the option for us, because users, that will be seeing Tableau report on our web-site may not even know, that they have accounts on Tableau side and that they need to explicitly logout from Tableau.

We tried to use [Tableau REST API logout endpoint](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_authentication.htm#sign_out) to logout user from Tableau after Auth0 logout, but it didn’t help (204 status code was returned, but user was not logged out from Tableau).

We also tried to et the callback URL to [this](https://prod-useast-b.online.tableau.com/wg/saml/SingleLogout/index.html) (it's Tableau logout URL) in Auth0 SAML addons and changed the binding value from Redirect To Post to call logout method of the Tableau. - didn't help

```
  "logout": {
    "callback": "https://prod-useast-b.online.tableau.com/wg/saml/SingleLogout/index.html"
  },
  "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Post"
```

[image: Tableau logout endpoint]

Then we tried to add logic to clear local storage, session storage, and cookies to remove auth0, tableau, and application data but still nothing changed, and the application sees the previous session of Tableau.

We are using the Tableau Lock logout method, it works correctly, and also we can see it in Auth0 logs, but it's not logging out from Tableau and not removing the Tableau session.

We need suggestions on how we can properly logout from Tableau session from our website.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The question is fairly specific. The additional information provides the contexts of what the OP is doing and what has been tried. In a nutshell, the execution of the Tableau logout endpoint - https://prod-useast-b.online.tableau.com/api/3.7/auth/signout - is returning a 204 - No Content - indicating that the session has been terminated on the server, yet we find that the session is still active when an unauthenticated user accesses the Tableau site.

Comment: Hi - Did you resolve this in the end? I think we are having the same problem. Thanks, Andy.